# Storing a re-sized image in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-resizing

I'm writing an application that gives the user the option to resize an image that they take and upload it to a service.  The resizing seems to work fine, but it's not storing the re-created image in the proper place, because the application doesn't seem to think that there's a photo loaded.

Note that the first function in the if statement (regarding "normal_size") works fine. I've tried to re-create those two lines in the additional size parameters, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not storing it.  This is driving me crazy.  Here's the code:

```
// Set image dictionaries
iInfoDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:info];
NSLog(@"infor ===== %@", info);
UIImage* image =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSLog(@"iImage name === %@", iImage);

// Determines path of image taken / chosen
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];

CGSize size;

// Not sure what this does other than dismissing the pickerViewController

NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);
[data writeToFile:appFile options:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Documents ==== %@", documentsDirectory);
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//    photo.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 

// IMAGE RESIZE CODE

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"normal_image"])    
{
    [photoData setObject:[iInfoDict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] forKey:@"image"];
     photo.image = [iInfoDict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"small_image"])
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake (600, 450);
    UIImage *origImage = [iInfoDict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    UIImage *destImage = [origImage resizedImage:size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

    NSLog(@"Image Size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(destImage.size));
    [photoData setObject:destImage forKey:@"image"];

    photo.image = destImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either I'm not understanding your question, or you don't understand what you're doing. I suspect the latter, based on the comment `// Not sure what this does other than dismissing the pickerViewController`, which is promptly followed by two lines that write the unresized image to the documents directory.

You probably want to resize the image *before* you write it out, so I suggest moving the writing to the end, after you've resized.

Delete the two lines:

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);
[data writeToFile:appFile options:nil error:nil];
```

And, at the end, insert these two lines (no guarantee, written from memory):

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo.image, 0.9);
[data writeToFile:appFile options:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The commented code is old and I haven't removed it yet. There's a function that pushes the photo to a service, and the first thing that it pushes out is a dictionary called "data", and it seems as though I'm writing to data after the image is resized, but for whatever reason the image is still appearing full-sized when we load it onto the website.

Comment: Oh my god, it was the photo.image rather than image being written that was the problem. Unbelievable.